# Does lucene return less results than expected

Tags: java, lucene

Sorry for the Vague Title. Here is my problem. I am using the following code to retrieve the results from lucene search

```
scoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
int numTotalHits = results.totalHits;
for (int i = 0; i < numTotalHits; i++) {
    int docId = hits[i].doc;
    Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
    System.out.println(i+":File name is: "+d.get("filename"));
    System.out.println(i+":File content is: "+d.get("contents"));
}
```

Now this code some times pops up a exception stating index exceeded array bounds.
So i used the below code and it does not cause any exception

```
scoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
int numTotalHits = results.totalHits;
for (int i = 0; i < numTotalHits-1; i++) {
    int docId = hits[i].doc;
    Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
    System.out.println(i+":File name is: "+d.get("filename"));
    System.out.println(i+":File content is: "+d.get("contents"));
}
```

Does this mean `results.totalHits` return `results.totalHits-2` number of search results?

Thank You..

Comment: You could use `hits.length` instead (to prevent the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

Comment: Have no idea about the `totalHits` behavior but, why can't you try setting `numTotalHits` to `hits.length`?

Comment: Hi i tried the same still getting same issue

Comment: @user2071270 To be clear, you are saying that replacing the third line in your example with `for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {` does not fix the issue?  If not, what does the stacktrace look like?  Is the exception NOT being thrown from the line `int docId = hits[i].doc;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`totalHits` is the total number of documents that match your query, which is usually different from the number of documents that you get back from lucene, which is what you get within the `hits` array.

Why is that? Think about a search engine: you execute a query, one million document match, but you only return 10 or 20 of them in a single page. One million would be the `totalHits` that you get back from lucene, but you would ask lucene only for the top 10 or 20 documents, which will be returned within the `hits` array.

There's only one case when `totalHits` is the same as `hits.length`: when your query matches a number of documents that's less or equal to the number of documents you asked for when executing the query, 10 in the example below:

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 10);
```